# else function to conditionally change View Cart Button message

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

On my WooCommerce products page, I have added a permanent View Cart button, with a customised message by using the below code without the "If" and "Else" sections. However, I want the message to change, depending on whether anything has been added to the cart or not.

I am not a wiz at PHP but am learning as fast as I can. I have tried using the else function, see below, but no good. I am sure that I am simply over-thinking it.

```php
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'proceed_to_cart');
function proceed_to_cart()
{
    global $woocommerce;

    if (is_cart() && WC()->cart->cart_contents_count == 0) {

        $checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url();
        echo '<a href="https://hqmissioncontrol.com/cart"  class="cart-button button alt wc-forward" >Add 3 of the same item to redeem a FREE GIFT at Cart (excludes Gift Cards)</a>';

    } else {

        $checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url();
        echo '<a href="https://hqmissioncontrol.com/cart"  class="cart-button button alt wc-forward" >View Cart</a>';

    }
}
```

It's the if argument that seems to be the main problem. I just get the generic "this site is experiencing technical difficulties" message no matter where I introduce it. Have tried replacing it with many different versions and even placed it before the first add_action, but nothing works.

Comment: Your code seems to be missing a closing curly bracket at the end...

Comment: Can you please check your server error logs for the exact error message?

Comment: The closing curly bracket stopped the error message, so thanks for that cabreahector, but now only the code after "else" is working, with the button showing "View Cart", regardless of cart contents.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, see below revised code. Thank you everyone, for your input.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'proceed_to_cart');
function proceed_to_cart(){
    global $woocommerce;

 if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 0 ) {

    $checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url();
    echo '<a href="https://hqmissioncontrol.com/cart"  class="cart-button button alt wc-forward" >Add 3 of the same item to redeem a FREE GIFT at Cart (excludes Gift Cards)</a>';

    } else {

    $checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url();
    echo '<a href="https://hqmissioncontrol.com/cart"  class="cart-button button alt wc-forward" >View Cart</a>';

    }
}
```